# OpenSocial create activity from submit click

Tags: javascript, jquery, opensocial

Hi I'm "playing with OpsnSocial" and think I get a lot of it (well thanks to Googles' bits) but one question if I may.  Creating an activity

Lets say I have a form like this (simple)

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="" id="testinput" value=""/>
<input type="submit" name="" id="" value=""/>
</form>
```

And I want to post the value of the text field (and or a message i.e "just posted" to the "users" activity.

Do I use a function like this?

```
function createActivity() {
  if (viewer) { 
    var activity = opensocial.newActivity({
      title: viewer.getDisplayName() 
          + ' VALUE FROM FORM '});
    opensocial.requestCreateActivity(activity, "HIGH", 
      function() { setTimeout(initAllData,1000); });
  }
};
```

1. If so, how do I pass the text field
   value to it - is it something like this?

   var testinput = document.getElementById("testinput");

so the function may look like

```
 function createActivity() {
  if (viewer) { 
    var activity = opensocial.newActivity({
      title: viewer.getDisplayName() 
          + testinput });
    opensocial.requestCreateActivity(activity, "HIGH", 
      function() { setTimeout(initAllData,1000); });
  }
};
```

2. And how do I trigger the function by using the submit button.  In my basic JQuery I would use `$('#submitID').submit(function(){ 'bits in here '});`
3. Is at "simple as that i.e. use the createActivity function and it will use the OS framework to "post" to the activity.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Umm actually it is that "easy" pretty obvious really use getElementbyID and yes it adds another activity